# PERL sh: script_init: command not found

Tags: linux, perl, bash, shell

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

my $file = "/mypath/myenv.env";

open (FILE, ". $file ;script_init $0 $* ;set |") or

  die ("Cannot Open $file ($!)");

while (<FILE>){

  chomp;

  print "$_\n";

}
```

Output:

```
sh: script_init: command not found
```

Problem:

I've break down the script to simulate this particular error,
$file = is the environment file to be loaded which included the path of script_init and other variables.

script_init = global script function that is used for script initialization for other scripts to load environment variables.

Scenario:

if I'm running the script_init in a regular shell or called in a script(not perl) it's working. example usage of script is like this.

```
#!/bin/ksh

. /mypath/myenv.env

script_init "$0" "$*"

main script.. etc...
```

or in shell

```
$ script_init anotherscript parameter
```

but if i call it in perl, it doesnt recognized the script_init which resulted to command not found even it loaded the `. $file (env)` needed for the script.

Comment: I can't believe that.  You rolled back the version that formatted your question!

Comment: `$* => Removed in Perl v5.10.0.` and was not equivalent to ksh $*

Comment: Is script_init a script file name? then when calling it add ./ before it.

Comment: Specify the interpreter in your perl code, say: `open (FILE, ". $file ; ksh script_init $0 $* ;set |") or` or `open (FILE, ". $file ; sh script_init $0 $* ;set |") or` depending upon what the interpreter is supposed to be.

Comment: @devnull: I don't think that makes sense. The `. $file` part has to be run in the same shell as the `script_init ...` part. Maybe something like `open FILE, qq{ksh -c ". $file ; script_init $0 $* ; set" |}`?

Comment: @ruakh Right. It seems that for a moment I completely forgot about the `source` part.

Comment: @devnull this "open FILE, qq{ksh -c ". $file ; script_init $0 $* ; set" |}" is the answer!! THANK YOU very much!! id really appreciate your help. it's now working

Comment: You should be aware, that this will still not work in an environment that does not know ksh. If that was the reason you wanted to switch from ksh script to Perl, that might be a problem.

Comment: @user2986766, you can provide an answer to your own question if you choose

Answer (score 0):

## !/usr/bin/perl -w

my $file = "/mypath/myenv.env";

**open FILE, qq{ksh -c ". $file ; script_init $0 $* ; set" |} or**

die ("Cannot Open $file ($!)");

while (< FILE >){

chomp;

print "$_\n";

}

Again many thanks!